# SQL Server Timeout based on locking?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a SQL query that normally runs for about .5 seconds and now, as our server gets slightly more busy, it is timing out. It involves a join on a table that is getting updated every couple seconds as a matter of course.

That is, the `EmailDetails` table gets updated from a mail service to notify me of reads,clicks, etc and that table gets updated every couple seconds as those notifications come through. I'm wondering if the join below is timing out because those updates are locking the table and blocking my SQL join.

If so, any suggestions how to avoid my timeout would be appreciated.

```
SELECT TOP 25
    dbo.EmailDetails.Id,
    dbo.EmailDetails.AttendeesId,
    dbo.EmailDetails.Subject,
    dbo.EmailDetails.BodyText,
    dbo.EmailDetails.EmailFrom,
    dbo.EmailDetails.EmailTo,
    dbo.EmailDetails.EmailDetailsGuid,
    dbo.Attendees.UserFirstName,
    dbo.Attendees.UserLastName,
    dbo.Attendees.OptInTechJobKeyWords,
    dbo.Attendees.UserZipCode,
    dbo.EmailDetails.EmailDetailsTopicId,
    dbo.EmailDetails.EmailSendStatus,
    dbo.EmailDetails.TextTo
FROM
    dbo.EmailDetails
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.Attendees ON (dbo.EmailDetails.AttendeesId = dbo.Attendees.Id)
WHERE 
    (dbo.EmailDetails.EmailSendStatus = 'NEEDTOSEND' OR 
     dbo.EmailDetails.EmailSendStatus = 'NEEDTOTEXT')  
    AND 
    dbo.EmailDetails.EmailDetailsTopicId IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    dbo.EmailDetails.EmailSendPriority,
    dbo.EmailDetails.Id DESC
```

Adding Execution Plan:

https://dl.dropbox.com/s/bo6atz8bqv68t0i/emaildetails.sqlplan?dl=0

It takes .5 seconds on my fast macbook but on my real server with magnetic media it takes 8 seconds.

Comment: That doesn't look like it's complex enough to need half a second to run. Is there a lot of data in the tables? What indexes do you have on the tables?

Comment: What is `set statistics io` result? Number of reads high? To test your blocking theory you could run at `read uncommitted` isolation level or look at waiting tasks whilst it is executing.

Comment: 2 million rows in EmailDetails and it is property indexed.

Comment: Turns out it is slow, 8 seconds.  20,000 rows in attendees table, 12 million in email details. I do have index on join column and EmailSendStatus and EmailDetailsTopicId.  I attached excution plan in original question.

Comment: Peter, can you provide the actual execution plan?

Comment: Hi Dan, kind of embarrassing to ask but I thought when I click on show plan and then donwload the plan that is the actual execution plan. I linked to it at the bottom of the original question.

Comment: *Estimated number of rows = 1?* Does this execution plan come from the production server? At the very least you need to update the database's statistics